# How to add glusterfs node in existing cluster with ansible

Tags: openshift, glusterfs

I have deploy OKD cluster with glusterfs and now i want to add one more glusterfs node but unable to find any playbook for it.

```
https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/master/playbooks/openshift-glusterfs
```

I found one playbook without description

```
https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/master/playbooks/openshift-glusterfs/upgrade.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add glusterfs node in existing group follow below

Change inventory like below add node with label in glusterfs

```
[glusterfs]
10.1.1.1  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]' 
10.1.1.2  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]'  openshift_node_labels="type=upgrade"
```

Now run playbook with following

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory2.ini openshift-ansible/playbooks/openshift-glusterfs/config.yml -e openshift_upgrade_nodes_label="type=upgrade"
```

As gluster already installed on 10.1.1.1, above script will add 10.1.1.2 in existing gluster cluster